# How do photodiode sensors respond to a spectrum of light frequencies/wavelength?

Tags: spectroscopy, light-emitting-diodes

I wanted to clarify about photodiodes used as sensors and about the response, which is given in the form of A/W:

[image]

What I want to ask about is what kind of response photodiodes normally give with a broader spectrum.  If you have a spectrum of light hitting a photodiode, would the responsivity be the average of the responsivities for each wavelength?  If the quantities of each are significantly uneven in intensity, would that require an optical filter to obtain accurate readings?  Because otherwise would the limitation of a basic photodiode be that you wouldn't be able to distinguish between an intense 500 nm wavelength light or a dimmer 900 nm light (assuming you couldn't use your eyes of course)?

Comment: I'm a little unclear what you mean. The responsivity to photons with a wavelength of 700 nm can be read off the graph, as can the responsivity to the other wavelengths. For a particular spectral distribution (intensity vs wavelength) you then convolute that distribution (with suitable units - be careful) with the responsivity curve.

Comment: @JonCuster, You should be doing a weighted average or overlap integral, not a convolution integral (where one of the variables of integration gets reversed).

Comment: @ThePhoton - fair enough. Haven't had enough coffee this afternoon. But you certainly don't 'sum' over a range.

Comment: Yeah, in retrospect, summing really wouldn't make sense, should've thought that out a little more.  Perhaps I could've included it in my question, but if you didn't want to use those kinds of mathematical techniques, would you generally need to use light filters to make sure you're only capturing desired wavelengths?

Comment: If the beam is reasonably narrow-band (i.e. if it comes from a laser or maybe even from an LED) it might be "good enough" to just use the responsivity value for the center wavelength.

Comment: Pretty much everything you said is correct. The need for filters and the lack of selective photodiodes is the reason I can't do pretty 90% of the photodiode projects I want to. Filters are expensive, very expensive. And bulky, and difficult to work with. I know of only two general ranges where you can still buy selective photo diodes ~900nm and 525nm. And those 525nm photodiodes consists of exactly two models from the same manufacturer which are otherwise identical except for FOV. Well, I guess I'm ignoring a lot of the SMD parts for colour calibration parts but those do not meet my needs.

Comment: I see.  Well I appreciate the answers, although obviously you can't get points from a comment (as I understand it), but thank you.